# How to access a list in another class in C#

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm incredibly new to C#, so please ignore my ignorance with this question. But I've searched online and can't find a solution that makes sense.

Basically, I have a list being stored in a CommonClass.CS, as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NewParkingApp
{
    public class CommonClass
    {
        public List < string > itemData = new List < string > ()  
            {  
                "Android",  
                "IOS",  
                "Windows Phone",  
                "Xamarin-IOS",  
                "Xamarin-Form",  
                "Xamarin_Android"  
            };  

    }
}
```

From another class, I'd then like to be able to access that list. This is what I have so far for the accessing class:

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UIKit;

namespace NewParkingApp
{
    public partial class ResultViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ResultViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            List<string> itemData = CommonClass.itemData;
            mainListview.Source = new TableViewSource(itemData);  
        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```

As an addition, it would also be useful to know how to add items to that list. But I'm guessing that should be pretty easy once I know how to access it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You either need to create an instance of `CommonClass` using `new` or make `itemData` `static` - though you should understand that much from any basic C# tutorial

Comment: `List<string> itemData = CommonClass.itemData;` this code does not compile

Comment: This question (and the code) reveals that you really need to understand the difference between a class and an _instance_ of that class

Comment: Looks like you need a static property in your `CommonClass`. You should use keyword `static` for that on declaring the member. In addition take a look at keyword `readonly`.

Comment: @Bahrom That was exactly what I needed - thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Before continuing any further you have to know whether you want this list to be *shared* among many objects, or *unique* for each instance of `CommonClass` you create.

As the comments mention:

- For a unique list per each `CommonClass` instance change the `itemData` assignment to use an instanced member:

  ```
  CommonClass commonClass = new CommonClass();
  List<string> itemData = commonClass.itemData;
  ```
- For a shared list add the `static` keyword to your class's `itemData` as such:

  `public static List<string> itemData = new List<string>()`

  Also note that the `List` class is only suitable for one thread operations only (i.e. only one object can read or write to the list at any given time), and once you start dealing with multi-threading you should opt for a thread-safe type.

Afterwards you can just use `itemData.Add("whatever");`, but really this can be easily checked online. [Here's just one example at dotnetperls.com](https://www.dotnetperls.com/list)

Answer (score 1):

```
//firt change your class commanclass with that code 

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace NewParkingApp
{
    public class CommonClass
    {
        public static List < string > itemData = new List < string > ()  
            {  
                "Android",  
                "IOS",  
                "Windows Phone",  
                "Xamarin-IOS",  
                "Xamarin-Form",  
                "Xamarin_Android"  
            };  

    }
}

//after class your main class in past 
using Foundation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UIKit;

namespace NewParkingApp
{
    public partial class ResultViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ResultViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            List<string> itemData = CommonClass.itemData;
            mainListview.Source = new TableViewSource(itemData);  
        }
    enter code here
        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }
    }
}
```